# The behaviour of r+ mode

Tags: python, python-2.7

Why when I add a word to the file via `r+` mode, **the first 3 lines** are truncated and that word is inserted?

So, in my case it means that r+ overwrites 3 lines. What's the problem?

My txt file:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
```

I opened it with a r+ mode and wrote the word "hello", so the result is:

```
hello
line 4
```

My code:

```
file_name = raw_input("--> ")

target = open(file_name, 'r+')

target.write('hello')

target.seek(0)
print target.read()
target.close()
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Your code works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

'r+' is used for read and write operation. 
I tried to replicate the scenario that you've shared.

In my output it displays:

```
hello1
line 2
line 3
line 4
```

Check your text file again or create a new one and try.